# How to Bulk-Unmark Marked Outlook Mails

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

I have an insane amount of red-marked Outlook mails (800). Is there a way to unmark the oldest 700 of them (alternatively to unmark mails which are older than a certain date)? Can this be done without unmarking everything and without clicking 700 times?

Comment: By marked do you mean they were flagged for follow up? The due date has passed so they turn red?

Comment: Yes, red for follow up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `tasks - view tab - change view - detailed list` This should bring them up as a list that you can sort by `due date`. Pick your date, select the top one and go to the bottom and hold `shift click` to select them all. `right click - mark complete` and they will no longer be red

If you have tasks in there as well, sort by `folder` and do the above steps for each folder you'd like to clear out